# rspec - testing validations and want to turn off callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec

I have a model with a relationship like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  before_save :default_values
  validates_presence_of :header

  def default_values
    if self.category.cat_is_enabled==true
      self.is_enabled=true
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like to just check the validates_presence_of with:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Item do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
  it "should have a header value" do
    mi=Item.create(:header => "").should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

but I get an error on this for "undefined method `cat_is_enabled' for nil:NilClass". How would I turn off default values? Is there a better way to test validations?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

#### Code

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.without_callback(callback, &block)
    method = self.send(:instance_method, callback)
    self.send(:remove_method, callback)
    self.send(:define_method, callback) {true}
    yield
    self.send(:remove_method, callback)
    self.send(:define_method, callback, method)
  end
end
```

#### Usage

```
Item.without_callback(:before_save) do
    mi = Item.create(:header => "").should_not be_valid
end
```

Credit: [article from Intridea](http://intridea.com/2009/3/12/temporarily-disable-activerecord-callbacks?blog=company).

Comment: hmm... this would only exist in test - is there a way to not bring in extra code (ie category would always exist). Kinding thinking out loud

Comment: answers question best (and i learned a little about ruby monkey-patching). Should probably use sol'n in other for testing validity

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply don't need to be trying to save the record to test this validation, and you should generally avoid touching the database more than you have to in tests anyway.

```
  it "should have a header value" do
    mi=Item.new(:header => "").should_not be_valid
  end
```